# Reference the source enumerable inside a method on that enumerable?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

Is there a way to reference the source enumerable inside a method running on that same enumerable?

For example, this code repeats the original enumerable range of 1-6:

```
IEnumerable<int> result = Enumerable.Range(1, 6)
    .Where(a => Enumerable.Range(1, 6).Count() % 2 == 0);
```

I want to know if there is a cleaner way to produce it with repeating the original enumerable, such as:

```
IEnumerable<int> result = Enumerable.Range(1, 6)
    .Where(a => [source reference].Count() % 2 == 0);
```

Yes, I know the following is a solution... But is there a way to do a direct reference to an in-memory enumerable, as demonstrated above?

```
IEnumerable<int> source = Enumerable.Range(1, 6);
IEnumerable<int> result = source.Where(a => source.Count() % 2 == 0);
```

I'm not looking for a specific answer to the lines of code above; they are just an example demonstrating what I want to know.

Comment: I don't think C# has a solution other than your last example. I think this last example is very understandable.

Comment: How do you expect to do reference an enumeration directly when you do not have a direct reference to it?

Comment: Why are you using a condition inside the `Where` query that will give the same result for every item?

Comment: Could you explain what exactly you want `result` to be?

Comment: Your query makes no sense at all. You probably want to use the current index of the element in the `Where` instead: `.Where((a,i) => i % 2 == 0);`. This condition is true for every second element.

Comment: perhaps I was hasty in giving him the benefit of the doubt that his *actual* use case was slightly more complex than "repeat the entire enumeration"... oh no, wait, he said exactly that in the question. sheesh, talk about missing the point :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the built-in `IEnumerable` extension methods can do what you want. They all accept lamba expressions that only operate on the individual items, so your expressions have no access to the parent container.

Nothing is stopping you from rolling your own, though, something like:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> WhereSource<T> ( this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<IEnumerable<T>, T, bool> predicate)
{
  foreach (var item in source)
  {
    if (predicate(source, item))
    {
      yield return item;    
    }
  }
}
```

Personally, I think your original solution is much clearer, more maintainable, and better than crafting your own custom extension method, but it's certainly possible.

Comment: Then the call site would look like `IEnumerable<int> result = Enumerable.Range(1, 6).WhereSource((source,item)=>source.Count() % 2 == 0 );` Which is a pretty useless example, as it's always `true`

Comment: All true statements, which is why the OP said "I'm not looking for a specific answer to the lines of code above; they are just an example demonstrating what I want to know."

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean this?

```
IEnumerable<int> source = Enumerable.Range(1, 6); //{1,2,3,4,5,6}
IEnumerable<int> result = source.Where((a, i) => i % 2 == 0); //{1,3,5}
IEnumerable<int> result2 = source.Where(a => a % 2 == 0); //{2,4,6}
```

Comment: He is taking mod of length of collection and not of index.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal I see that... But is there any sense in that...He could do just `6 % 2`...why make an enumeration??

Comment: May be that value is passed as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't because that `Enumerable.Range(1, 6))` do not have a name.

how will you call an entity that do not have a name.

Your 3rd snippet is the only solution that you can use because not it has a name to refer to.

However you can do

```
int length = 6; // Here hard-coded but can be passed from a parameter.
IEnumerable<int> source = Enumerable.Range(1, Length);
IEnumerable<int> result = source.Where(a => length % 2 == 0);
```